# Why aren't my attempts to freeze time not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want it so when the player moves his mouse on an object the time freezes and he can't move anymore. I tried different methods but it just doesn't freeze the time.

```
private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        PlayRandomSound();
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you use Time.deltaTime for your player movement?

Comment: If you set timescale to 0 anything that uses time stops

Comment: So, your attempts are working? "Why AREN'T my attempts to freeze time NOT working?"

Comment: Iggy I use FPScontroller from standard assets

Comment: BugFinder It doen't seem to work i even tried the code fromthe unity docs

Comment: Enimgravity I didn't understand what you said. Can you repeat it in an other way?

Comment: @Ranbee I think the behavior you are getting is exactly what we expect when timescale is set to 0, please explain clearly what you expected to happen

Comment: BugFinder I expect the player to completely not be able to move. Like a complete freeze of any actions and just the sound. A freeze of time if that.